# CoreLocation Framework Issues

Tags: iphone, gps

I have used Core location framework to receive my GPS coordinates in my IPOD.First time i can get the Latitude and longitude, then i got an error message , kCLErrorDomain Code=0 Operation Could not be completed.

But the error message never change.I think first time only it works

## This is My code

```
#import "CoreLocationDemoViewController.h"

@implementation CoreLocationDemoViewController

@synthesize CLController;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CLController = [[CoreLocationController alloc] init];
    CLController.delegate = self;
    [CLController.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {
    speedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SPEED: %f", [location speed]];
    latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LATITUDE: %f", location.coordinate.latitude];
    longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LONGITUDE: %f", location.coordinate.longitude];
    altitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ALTITUDE: %f", [location altitude]];
    errorLabel.text = @"";
}

- (void)locationError:(NSError *)error {

    if(!CLController) //.text )
    {   
    errorLabel.text = [error description];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [CLController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Anybody know what are the issues, help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
VKS

Comment: Please mark the code up as code. It's hardly readable.

Comment: @vks, you cant get current location in Ipod. Because Ipod dont have GPS facility.

Comment: but i got correct GPS cordinates first time,then got the error message,my ipod has wifi connection

Comment: which location you have got at 1st time? Have you got Cupertino?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes iPod doesn't have GPS functionality. Test your app either in simulator or iPhone not on iPod.

Comment: but i got correct GPS cordinates first time,then got the error message,my ipod has wifi connection